# Removing rows where all but one column match in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have the following table:

```
id | name  | time      | action | entered
---+-------+-----------+--------+--------
 1 | james | today     | x      |
 1 | james | today     | x      | yes
 1 | james | today     | y      |
 1 | james | today     | y      | yes
 2 | carl  | today     | x      | 
 2 | carl  | today     | y      |
 3 | casey | yesterday | x      |
 3 | casey | yesterday | x      | yes
 3 | casey | yesterday | y      |
 3 | casey | yesterday | y      | yes
 4 | john  | today     | x      | yes
```

I want to remove the rows where the value of `entered` is "yes", and there is another row with the same values at all other columns except in `entered`.

In the example above - rows 2,4,8,10 should be deleted.

There is a primary key **on all five** columns.

How can I achieve this?
Solutions in **MySQL or in Python** will be accepted.

Comment: Why row 11 shouldnt be deleted it also has entered = "yes"

Comment: @RaymondNijland because there isn't another row that matches the other values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE t1
FROM tablename AS t1
JOIN (
  SELECT id, `name`, `time`, `action`, count(*) AS cnt
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY id, `name`, `time`, `action`
  HAVING cnt > 1
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
AND t1.entered = 'yes'
;
```

Just replace `tablename` to your table...

Comment: I missed to check row 7

Answer (score 0):

Confident as I am, I suggest you make a back-up before testing this...

```
DELETE x 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id = x.id
   AND y.name = x.name
   AND y.time = x.time
   AND y.action = x.action
   AND y.entered <> x.entered
 WHERE x.entered = 'yes';
```

Comment: this solution is too heavy for a large data set.. didn't mention the size in the post though,

Comment: On an appropriately indexed schema, this should be ok